# ffmpeg mov (ProRes) to mp4

Tags: video, debian, ffmpeg

I have a .mov file that I am trying to convert to mp4 or avi and having a lot of issues.  These are files that were given to me to convert 8mm to digital.

I am very new to ffmpeg and conversions.

```
debian:/home/HomeMovies# ffmpeg -i Brink\ 8mm\ Reel\ 01.mov -vcodec libx264 -acodec libfaac home1.mp4
ffmpeg version 0.7.16, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
      built on May  2 2014 14:22:53 with gcc 4.4.5
      configuration: --enable-libdc1394 --prefix=/usr --extra-cflags='-Wall -g ' --cc='ccache cc' --    enable-shared --enable-libmp3lame --enable-gpl --enable-libvorbis --enable-pthreads --enable-libfaac --enable-libxvid --enable-postproc --enable-x11grab --enable-libgsm --enable-libtheora --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libx264 --enable-libspeex --enable-nonfree --disable-stripping --enable-avfilter --enable-libdirac --disable-decoder=libdirac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libschroedinger --disable-encoder=libschroedinger --enable-version3 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-librtmp --extra-libs=-lgcrypt --disable-altivec --disable-armv5te --disable-armv6 --disable-vis
   libavutil    50. 43. 0 / 50. 43. 0
   libavcodec   52.123. 0 / 52.123. 0
   libavformat  52.111. 0 / 52.111. 0
   libavdevice  52.  5. 0 / 52.  5. 0
   libavfilter   1. 80. 0 /  1. 80. 0
   libswscale    0. 14. 1 /  0. 14. 1
   libpostproc  51.  2. 0 / 51.  2. 0 

Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 2997.00 (2997/1) -> 29.97 (2997/100)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Brink 8mm Reel 01.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2014-11-18 21:14:29
  Duration: 00:03:02.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 204586 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: Apple ProRes 422 (HQ), 1920x1080, 204550 kb/s, PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 2997 tbn, 2997 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-11-18 21:14:29
    Stream #0.1(eng): Data: tmcd / 0x64636D74
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-11-18 21:16:11
File 'home1.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
[buffer @ 0x9311d00] Invalid pixel format string '-1'
Error opening filters!
```

Comment: Can you try again with a more recent version of ffmpeg? We have 2.5.x already, so 0.7.x is *way* outdated. Download one here: http://ffmpeg.org/download.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When converting 4:2:2 footage like proRes to 4:2:0 codecs like x264 you have to explicitly tell it to change the pixel format. Add this to your command line: `-pix_fmt yuv420p`. But first update your ffmpeg like slhk said.

Comment: failing to do this may deliver mp4s that play fine on some platforms and not on others. notably, safari (quicktime) shows very strange noise and chrome works well (2015/05)